# What causes these artifacts when printing a pdf?

Tags: pdf, printing

Here is a snippet from an [article](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/221091814_Robust_topology_control_for_indoor_wireless_sensor_networks/file/d912f50b27fe40591e.pdf) I'm reading: it displays perfectly on screen:

[image]

However, when printed some lines appear to be bold (line 5 and 11 in the picture):

[image]

Another strange behavior; this is how it looks if I select text on the pdf:

[image]

And this is the result when print to xps:

[image]

What exactly is causing this? It seems that everything is all right in viewing mode, but goes wrong during the print.

The document is produced with pdfTeX-1.40.3, it's a pdf v1.4 (Acrobat 5.x) and I'm opening it on Adobe Reader 10.1.9, running on Windows 7 x64.

Comment: A few questsions; have you tried using more than one printer, have you run more than one copy, do you know what software was used to make the PDF? I know these seem pretty obvious, but it'll help get to the bottom of it if we can exclude the simple options.

Comment: I only have access to one printer, I found some information about the document but I don't think I can go deeper, it's an article I downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

In the PDF reader printer options,

Open PDF > Control P > The advanced button

Try enabling "print as image"